# Relating the argument of a hyperbolic trig function to area

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

Based on the definition of the hyperbolic trig functions (in terms of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$) it's easy to show that the point $\big(\cosh(\alpha),\sinh(\alpha)\big)$ falls on the unit hyperbola ($x^2-y^2=1$). But one may ask: what is $\alpha$?

It turns out that $\alpha$ is the area of the region bounded by the unit hyperbola and the line segment joining the origin and $\big(\cosh(\alpha),\sinh(\alpha)\big)$ and the line segment joining the origin and $\big(\cosh(\alpha),-\sinh(\alpha)\big)$.

I just tried and failed to prove that this is true. Maybe I just gave up too soon or was lacking the proper insight. Does anyone know how to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Mirroring the polar coordinates proof for the area of a circular sector, introduce "hyperbolic polar coordinates"
$$
P(r, t) = (r\cosh t, r\sinh t),\quad 0 \leq r,\quad -\infty < t < \infty,
$$
which cover the quarter plane $0 \leq x$, $-x < y < x$ containing the right branch of the hyperbola $x^{2} - y^{2} = 1$, $x > 0$. The Jacobian is easily calculated to be
$$
\det DP(r, t) = r,
$$
and the region $R$ bounded by the hyperbola, the ray from the origin through $(\cosh\alpha, \sinh\alpha)$, and the ray from the origin through $(\cosh\alpha, -\sinh\alpha)$ is the rectangle $R^{*}$ in the $(r, t)$-plane defined by $0 \leq r \leq 1$, $-\alpha \leq t \leq \alpha$. By the change of variables theorem,
$$
\text{area of $R$}
  = \int_{R} dx\, dy
  = \int_{R^{*}} |\det DP(r, t)|\, dr\, dt
  = \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} \int_{0}^{1} r\, dr\, dt
  = \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} \frac{1}{2}\, dt 
  = \alpha.
$$

(Diagrams can be found in [my answer to Parametric equation - of a hyperbola](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1495478/86418).)